# "undefined function exif_read_data()" error only via Cron

Tags: php, function, undefined

I am facing trouble running a PHP script via Cron. When I execute the same script from a browser, it works just fine.

The Cron service outputs this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function `exif_read_data()` in /homessd/xxx/my-functions.php on line 88

Comment: Maybe your web server and the command-line `php` interpreter use different `php.ini` files which could cause this.

Comment: hmmm.. quite possible. let me ask this to hosting provider. thanx for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by jotik, i have checked with my hosting provider and found that a different php was being used via cron which was creating the problem. After fixing the path to correct php, the problem is solved.